# A question about inequalites over integers

Tags: number-theory, inequality, analytic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Given a positive integer $n$, we can say that

i). $2^x \le n < 2^{x+1}$

ii). $3^y \le n < 3^{y+1}$

iii). $5^z \le n < 5^{z+1}.$

By using the first two inequalities, can we find or give an inequality for $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Edit. I can get the inequalities by taking logarithms like

$$ z < \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 5} (x+1) \text{  or  }< \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 5} x < z+1  .$$
but I rather want something about the integerness properties of $z$. For instance, by knowing the values of $x$ or $y$ modulo some number $m$, can we say something about $z \pmod m$?

Comment: Yes, just take logarithms.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: "I rather want something about the integerness properties of z."  There's nothing to be done about "intergerness".

Comment: This is too vague.  Do you mean things like $3^y < 5\cdot 5^z < 10\cdot 2^x$?  There are too many possibilities and nothing of this has anything to do with $x, y, z$ being integers anyway.

Comment: Either the inequality you wrote or the last example I gave in the question.